# How to separate a string delimitated by @ in a txt file on a c program?

Tags: c, delimiter

I have a txt file that I have to read in a c program, the file contains a string of numbers separated by an @, it looks like this:

```
-24.5@5.23@4.58@112.1275@524963.8974632841@18.37343308266859@1412046264002
```

I upload the file to the program using the `fopen` function, and printed it with the `fprintf`, but I haven't found a method for separate the numbers

I found this method but it doest work:

```
sscanf(line, "%s\t%s", position, activity);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Explaining the behavior you observed is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtok` function. Here an example:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   const char str[100] = "-24.5@5.23@4.58@112.1275@524963.8974632841@18.37343308266859@1412046264002";
   const char s[2] = "@";
   char *token;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while (token != NULL) 
   {
      printf("%s\n", token);
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: `const char str[100]` --> `char str[100]`